# Does UIActionSheet reload the main view when it's called?

Tags: ios7, uitextview, uiactionsheet

I have a UITextView in my view and I have a drag and drop ability for users. If I move the UITextView using the drag and drop and then I activate the UIActionSheet it will automatically move the UITextView back to where it was located originally in the StoryBoard. I've traced through this and it moves this object before the willPresentActionSheet and didPresentActionSheet delegate methods are called. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out the issue. I had Auto Layout enabled and so for some reason when you pull up an UIActionSheet it treats it almost like a rotate screen and activates an auto layout. I disabled that and it worked fine.